# Bad State: you cannot add items while items are being added from addStream

Tags: dart, flutter, reactive-programming, reactive

I am new to flutter, dart or reactive programming in general.

I suppose, I am calling add() on the BehaviorSubject while items are being added to that stream by some previous call.

How can I avoid this bad state? How can I add the event once the event in previous call have been added?

Comment: Did _you_ call `addStream`? That call should return a `Future` which will fire once the stream is done and it's safe to call `add` again.

Comment: ok. thanks i think that will help.

Comment: make sure you don't have any other stream 'piped' to the BehaviorSubject that causes the crash

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamController/addStream.html): "Events must not be added directly to this controller using add, addError, close or addStream, until the returned future is complete." You may want to wait for the Future callback first before calling add().

Comment: Looking at the documentation this future won't complete until the added stream is done. Confused as to how this method is supposed to be used.